# Confusion with L2 Regularization in Back-propagation

Tags: backpropagation, mathematics, regularization

In a very simple language, this is L2 regularization

$\hspace{3cm}$$Loss_R$ = $Loss_N + \sum w_i^2$

$Loss_N$ - *Loss without regularization*

$Loss_R$ - *Loss with regularization*

When implementing [[Ref]](https://www.kaggle.com/mtax687/l2-regularization-of-neural-network-using-numpy), we simply add the derivative of the new penaty to the current delta weight,

$\hspace{3cm}$$dw = dw_N + constant*w$

$dw_N$ - *Weight delta without regularization*

What I think - *L2 regularization is achieved with the last step only i.e. the weight is penalized.*

My question is -

 *Why do we then add the loss in the total loss as done in the first equation. Will, it not put an additional penalty during back-prop( *On $dw_N$ component*) for each weight because of increased Loss. I can understand if it is for console print purpose but it is not, I believe.*

I know I am missing something very simple.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The second equation follows from the first; the implementation never really needs the first equation, but it more clearly shows what the regularization is doing.